# Fast refresh failing when dynamically importing components in Vite using React and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I am trying to create a multistep form, I have my data in a separate file for constants like this

import { lazy } from 'react';

```
export const steps = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Personal Info',
    component: lazy(() => import('../components/PersonalInfo')),
  },
];
```

I pass it to a custom hook in a context

```
const dataSteps = useMultiStep(steps);

const { next, back, currentStep, isFirst } = dataSteps;
```

This is the customhook

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { MultistepProps } from '../@types/Multiform';

const useMultiStep = (steps: MultistepProps[]) => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);

  const isLast = step === steps?.length - 1;
  const isFirst = step === 0;

  const next = (): void => {
    if (isLast) return;
    setStep((current) => current + 1);
  };

  const back = (): void => {
    if (isFirst) return;
    setStep((current) => current - 1);
  };

  return {
    step,
    next,
    back,
    currentStep: steps[step],
    isFirst,
  };
};

export default useMultiStep;
```

I use the dynamically components here

```
import FormInterface from './interface/FormInterface';
import useApp from './hooks/useApp';
import { Suspense } from 'react';
function App() {
  const data = useApp();

  const { currentStep, next, back, isFirst } = data;

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    next();
  };

  return (
    <FormInterface>
      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        className="flex flex-col h-full py-5 group"
        noValidate={true}
      >
        {currentStep.component && (
          <>
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold text-marineBlue">
              {currentStep?.name}
            </h1>

            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
              <currentStep.component /> //here
            </Suspense>

            <div
              className={`mt-4 sm:mt-auto flex ${
                isFirst ? 'justify-end' : 'justify-between'
              }`}
            >
              <button
                type="button"
                className={`hover:text-marineBlue font-bold text-coolGray py-2 px-5 rounded-md text-[13px] ${
                  isFirst ? 'hidden' : 'block'
                }`}
                onClick={back}
              >
                Go Back
              </button>
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="hover:bg-purplishBlue bg-marineBlue text-white py-2 px-5 rounded-md text-[12px] group-invalid:pointer-events-none group-invalid:opacity-30 self-end"
              >
                Next Step
              </button>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </form>
    </FormInterface>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My vite config is this

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

After trying EVERYTHING I still get this errors not the first renders but when the component reloads

> App.tsx:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'currentStep' of 'data' as it is null.
> at App (App.tsx:7:11)
> at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
> at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:13)
> at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:16)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
> at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:7)
> at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:12)
> at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:5)

I believe it's a HRM issue since it's like loading the whole page insted of only the component, for that the states are lost and the info on the `useMultisteps` is lost but I just can't find a way to make it work, please help me our teach me a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your state is getting lost when you update the component (likely because the useApp() hook is returning `null` before the data is ready).

1. Try to wrap the stateful component in a React memo(). In this way your component state is preserved across HMR updates.

e.g. wrap the useApp hook in the useMemo hook to ensure that it only gets called once:

```
const data = useMemo(() => useApp(), []);
```

To cap it up, this will ensure that the useApp hook is only called once and that its return value is memoized, even if the component is re-rendered due to HMR.

2. second suggestion: try to modify your code like the below:

   const { currentStep, next, back, isFirst } = data ?? {};

This will ensure that the destructuring operation only occurs if the data object is not null.

Comment: What do You mean with stateful componente? The components that i want to rende dynamically?

Comment: just updated the answer. Check it up please.